# encrypting on java using ceaser cipher

Tags: java, arrays

please i need help what is wrong with that code . every time i run that code i got an Arrayoutofboundexception error so what is wrong please help,i think i put a good algorithm to make a cipher text so please help and forget about the spaces assume that the word is without spaces. it is just a school project for a junior

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int key = 11;
    int result = 0;

    char Alpha[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
            't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter text to be encrypted :");
    String plainText = s.nextLine();
    char targetText[] = plainText.toCharArray();
    char EncryptText[] = new char[plainText.length()];
    int encryption[] = new int[plainText.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < Alpha.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < targetText.length; j++) {
            if (targetText[j] == Alpha[i]) {
                try {
                    result = (j + key) % Alpha.length;
                    if (result < 0) {
                        result += Alpha.length;
                    } else {
                        encryption[i] = result;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < encryption.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Alpha.length; j++) {

            if (encryption[i] == j) {
                try {
                    EncryptText[i] = Alpha[j];
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i <EncryptText.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("the encryptedText is " + EncryptText[i]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What line is getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? What is the input?

Comment: the lines that inside the try catch

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a number between 0 and 25 (inclusive), `encryption` is an array of unknown length (length of input, but we don't know input), so `encryption[i]` is inherently wrong.

Did you mean `encryption[j] = result;`?

Notice that second set of loops reverse the meaning of `i` and `j`!!!
Bad style. Very confusing. Even to you, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Your main loop should be something like this....

```
for (int j = 0 ; j < target Text.Length() ; j++){
     EncryptedText [j] = (((targetText[j] - 'a') + key ) % 26) + 'a'; 
}
```

Sorry for formatting I'm on mobile...

Edit: fixed formatting

Edit2: also the line `EncryptText[i] = result;` is probably whats giving you the error assuming that your plaintext is less than 26 characters long. I think you mean't `EncryptText[j] = result;` as Andreas suggested.